# SQL Server full text searching between long continous words

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am trying to search for 1005 in p1005 string but it doesn't find any result.

I have used query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE CONTAINS (Name, '"*1005*"')

SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE CONTAINS (Name, '1005') 

SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE FREETEXT (Name, '"1005"')
```

Is there a way to search a word between the words?

Answer (score 0):

I am not necessarily a very skilled SQL DBA, but it seems that you can only perform prefix searches using CONTAINS when you want to search inside a word for example. For instance, following query would work:

```
USE MyDb;  
GO  
SELECT Name  
FROM myDb.Places  
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, ' "Chain*" ');  
GO
```

....but the one you would need won't work, because it is a suffix search.

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Name,' "*1005" ')
```

I would try to refactor this to use the LIKE operator. If anyone has another idea, I would also be glad to find out an answer.

Comment: I have updated it meanwhile. Please look at it carefully. It should be(Name,' "*1005" ') So first ' then " then * then search term then " and then '

Comment: I just tried it once again in one of my databases and the model that I proposed worked for me. What I can think about is that maybe your column type is a numeric type or maybe your should not have space between Contains and (). From what I can see here you have a space after CONTAINS. I am also curious about an answer that'll work for you.

Comment: As a list hint, you might also try to use the LIKE operator as described here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: Ok, I digged a little bit and found out that you can perform only prefix searches with contains, which means search like Contains(' "p100*" ') but  not Contains(' "*p100" ') . You should definitely use the LIKE operator in this case. I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: yes, I found it too. Thanks, but LIKE is very “heavy” operation. Also another full text search like Elasticsearch  сan't do this too.